# search bar add as a base template into one class views Django

Tags: python, django, search, django-class-based-views

## views.py

```
class BookList(ListView):
    model = Book
    context_object_name = 'book_list'
    template_name = 'books/book_lists.html'
    paginate_by = 12
    extra_context = {
        'category_list': Category.objects.all(),
        'author_list': Author.objects.all(),
        'language_list': Language.objects.all(),
    }

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if query:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(
                Q(name_of_the_book__icontains=query) |
                Q(author__first_name__icontains=query) |
                Q(category__name__icontains=query)
            )
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all()
        return object_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        context.update(self.extra_context)
        return context

class BookDetails(DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'books/book_details.html'
    extra_context = {
        'category_list': Category.objects.all(),
        'author_list': Author.objects.all(),
        'language_list': Language.objects.all(),
    }

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        context.update(self.extra_context)
        print(context)
        return context
```

## base.html

```
<form class="example" action="" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px">
  <input type="text" name='q' placeholder="Search...">
  <button type="submit" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form><br>
```

Here, BookList view is my homepage and when I'm searching from here then it's working good but when I'm going to Detail page then it doesn't work. Cause from BookDetailView I didn't send any kinds of a query in the base.html template. So, in this case, How can I send a query from DetailView or is there any built-in decorator for DetailView or can i use just one Class that will work for searching dynamically all template?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the url of your `BookList` view in the form:

```
<form class="example" action="{% url "the name of your route for the BookList" %}" style="margin:auto;max-width:300px">
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bernhard Vallant. It's working fine for me.